# Unresolved external symbol __report_rangecheckfailure

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, linker-errors

I have this simple program which creates a prompt for password. I have both Visual Studio 2012 and 2010 installed. It works on 2010, but on 2012 I get this error: `unresolved external symbol __report_rangecheckfailure referenced in function main`. Also, I modified the code by moving everything from main to another function. That works on both versions.

There must be some problems with some library, but which one and how do I solve it? Thanks.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int key, i;
    char pwd[64];

    printf("Enter passphrase: ");

    key=getch();        
    i=0;
    while (key!=13)
    {
        cout<<"*";      
        pwd[i++]=key;
        key=getch();
    }

    pwd[i++]='\0';

    cout<<strlen(pwd)<<endl;
    for (i=0; i<strlen(pwd); i++)
        cout<<pwd[i]<<endl;

    getch();
}
```

Comment: This error is encountered most often while migrating a VS project from an older version to a newer one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the project was started in VS 2010, then VS will use MS VS 10.0 C libs. If you start it with 2012, it will use vers. 11.0 libs. VS 2012 will call __report_rangecheckfailure when compiling, but it is not in the same place in version 10 as it is in 11. You can update your project to VS 2012 in the main project menu, or disable the buffer security check (by `/GS-` option).

[Further Reading on VS /gs compiler option](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sdl/archive/2012/01/26/enhancements-to-gs-in-visual-studio-11.aspx)

Comment: I have read about this. I should've mentioned it. But this is not the case. I have two different projects. But I did copy the include folders from 10 folders to 11. Don't know why they were missing. I only used 11 for c# 'till now. Your solution worked. Did it like here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8dbf701c.aspx. Why is this happening?